# Pointwise absolute and uniform convergence of a series of functions for $0<k<1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

To study for $k\in\Bbb R^+$ the pointwise, absolute and uniform convergence in $\Bbb R$ of the following
series of functions:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos n^k x}{1+n^k}$$
One has obviously, for each $x\in\Bbb R$:
$$\left|\frac{\cos n^k x}{1+n^k}\right|\leq\frac1{1+n^k}\qquad\forall x\in\Bbb R,$$ and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty1/(1+n^k)$ converges if $k>1$, so in that case there is total convergence (hence uniform absolute, pointwise over all $x\in\mathbb R$). If $k=1$ the series becomes
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(nx)}{1+n};$$
this series is shown, by the Abel-Dirichlet criterion, or by techniques peculiar to Fourier series, to be punctually convergent, except for $x\in2\pi\Bbb Z$; and it is also shown to converge uniformly on any set that has strictly positive distance from $2\pi\Bbb Z$  again by techniques related to this criterion.

> But I would not be able to discuss its absolute convergence, and nothing I could say in the case $0<k<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that the series never converges absolutely, while conditional convergence doesn't hold for any $x$ when $k \le1/2$ and it does hold (uniformly for $x$ in compacts away from $0$) for $x \ne 0$ when $1/2<k<1$

Since (by the Feijer criterion) it is known that for any $x \ne 0$ we have that $n^kx$ is uniformly distributed modulo $2\pi$ when $0<k<1$, it immediately follows that the series can never converge absolutely in this case.

(as for every $N$ we can find a positive proportion $\sim cN$ of $N/2 \le n \le N, c>0$ fixed for which $|\cos n^kx| \ge 1/10$ say so the partial sum from $N/2$ to $N$ of the absolute series is at least $cN^{1-k}/10$ so is unbounded).

Note that $|\cos b - \cos a| \le |b-a|$ so $\cos b \ge \cos a -|b-a|$. But for $1 \le m \le n$ and $0<k<1$ we have (by MVT) $|m^k - n^k| \le k(n-m)m^{k-1}$ so $\cos (m+j)^kx \ge \cos m^kx-kxjm^{k-1}$ so summing from $j=1,..A$ we have $$\sum_{j=1}^A\frac{\cos (m+j)^kx }{1+(m+j)^k}  \ge \cos m^kx\sum_{j=1}^A\frac{1 }{1+(m+j)^k}-kxm^{k-1}\sum_{j=1}^A\frac{j }{1+(m+j)^k}.$$

But $\sum_{j=1}^A\frac{j }{1+(m+j)^k} \le A^2m^{-k}$ so $kxm^{k-1}\sum_{j=1}^A\frac{j }{1+(m+j)^k}\le kxA^2m^{-1}$, while if $A < m/3$ say we have $\sum_{j=1}^A\frac{1 }{1+(m+j)^k} \ge Am^{-k}/2$

Wlog $x \ne 0$ (otherwise series divergent directly) so we can choose a sequence $m_n \to \infty$ st $\cos m^k x\ge 1/2$ when $m=m_n$ and for such $\cos m^kx\sum_{j=1}^A\frac{1}{1+(m+j)^k} \ge Am^{-k}/4$

Choosing $A=A(m)$ integral around $\frac{m^{1-k}}{8kx}$ (which we clearly can for all $m$ large enough) we get that $$\sum_{j=1}^A\frac{\cos (m+j)^kx }{1+(m+j)^k}  \ge Am^{-k}/4 -kxA^2m^{-1} \ge \frac{m^{1-2k}}{32kx}$$ and clearly this doesn't converge to zero as long as $k \le 1/2$ so for infinitely many $m=m_n \to \infty$ the partial series from $m$ to $m+A(m)$ doesn't converge to zero, which contradicts the Cauchy criterion of convergence, so the series diverges!

On the other hand, for $x \ne 0$, using the first derivative test for exponential sums (noting that the first derivative of $y \to xy^k$ is $kxy^{k-1}$, so when $N \le n \le 2N$ we have an inferior bound of $C_xN^{k-1}$ on it), we have $$\sum_{N \le n \le 2N}\cos n^k x \ll_x N^{1-k}$$ uniform in $N$ so by partial summation and the usual dyadic trick, it follows that the partial sums $\sum_{N \le n \le M}\frac{\cos n^kx }{1+n^k}$ are $\ll_x N^{1-2k}$ which of course goes to zero precisely when $k>1/2$, so the Cauchy criterion shows convergence in that case.

The argument above also shows the convergence being uniform in $x$ on any compact away from $0$ so the result is a continuous function on $\mathbb R^*$ that grows like $x^{k-1}$ near $0$ by a standard argument, so in particular, it is locally integrable at zero.

Note that an upper boundness condition on $|x|$ is required so the derivative $kxn^{k-1}$ is less than $1$ in absolute value for all $n$ large enough when $x$ is in a specific set and the first derivative test is applicable, while the lower boundness condition is of course required so the $C_xN^{1-k}$ bound for the cosine sum has $C_x \le C$ for $x$ in a specific set, so the bound given by the first derivative test is uniform in $x$.

Comment: I didn't understand much but I will study your solution very carefully. Thank you immensely. +1.

Comment: What is the Wlog?

Comment: Without losing generality - note that the above applies to series where you do not have necessarily same power in numerator vs denominator (terms are $\cos xn^k/(1+n^r), r\le 1$ to make it nontrivial) though for $k>1$ the results are less precise since it's much more difficult to estimate the corresponding cosines sums)

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have received the 50 points+15?

Comment: Happy to be of help - yes got the points